# Is there a workaround to nest shared steps in the Microsoft Test Manager?

Tags: tfs, reusability, microsoft-test-manager, manual-testing

In the MTM/TFS I can create a "shared step" that contains several actual steps. My test cases can then "call" or reuse that shared step, e.g.:

```
Test Case:
  <call shared step 1>
  <call shared step 2>
shared step 1:
  do something
  do something else
shared step 2:
  do something
  do something else
```

We're now facing the problem that we have many similar test cases that consist mostly of calls to shared steps, so we'd like to create a second level of shared steps, i.e. nested shared steps:

```
Test Case 1:
  <call shared step level 2>
  perform some action
Test Case 2:
  <call shared step level 2>
  perform another action
shared step level 2:
  <call shared step 1>
  <call shared step 2>
shared step 1:
  do something
  do something else
shared step 2:
  do something
  do something else
```

The MTM and the TFS won't let me do this via the UI. According to [these](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d0d6e1d0-7295-4ffb-a37d-3fd41ec3501b/nested-shared-steps?forum=vststest) two [posts](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb64cd32-ef79-49bf-b83c-c2b4fbd09063/shared-steps-inside-shared-steps?forum=vsmantest), it's not currently possible. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Comment: This is one request I have never encountered, can you email me a deeper description? Maybe we can work something out.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this and no workaround.

Raise it as a request on http://visualstudio.uservoice.com